# How to use intent to open email application

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

Hi am new to android development and have come across a problem. I am whatching this tutorial video from  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqk154QSe8Y#t=158 (The New Boston) and as far as I can tell I have the same exact code however the for some reason my code won't open email app on the tap of the button and the call of the Intent

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I hate you");
emailIntent.setType("plain/type");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

The button does work because I am capable of changing text color but the email intent does not open

**I there something I am doing wrong??**

This is the complete code---

package com.infitenothing.word;

```
import com.infitenothing.dogcat.R;

import android.R.anim;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Email extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText personsEmail, intro, personsName, stupidThings, hatefulAction,
        outro;
String emailAdd, beginning, name, stupidAction, hatefulAct, out;
Button sendEmail;
TextView color;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email);
    initializeVars();
    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initializeVars() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    personsEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmails);
    intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIntro);
    personsName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    stupidThings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etThings);
    hatefulAction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAction);
    outro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOutro);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSentEmail);
    color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    color.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated();
    String emailaddress[] = { emailAdd };
    String message = "Well hello "
            + name
            + " I just wanted to say "
            + beginning
            + ".  Not only that but I hate when you "
            + stupidAction
            + ", that just really makes me crazy.  I just want to make you "
            + hatefulAct
            + ".  Welp, thats all I wanted to chit-chatter about, oh and"
            + out
            + ".  Oh also if you get bored you should check out www.mybringback.com"
            + '\n' + "PS. I think I love you...   :(";
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I hate you");
    emailIntent.setType("plain/type");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
}

private void convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    emailAdd = personsEmail.getText().toString();
    beginning = intro.getText().toString();
    name = personsName.getText().toString();
    stupidAction = stupidThings.getText().toString();
    hatefulAct = hatefulAction.getText().toString();
    out = outro.getText().toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: you are missing the startActivity(emailIntent) call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created the intent, but never signaled it to execute. Add this code :

```
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out and may be you can find what you were missing in your code

`Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
it.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
String [] to  = {"Your-Email@example.com"};
it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hii this was sent from my App");
it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey Whatsupp!! ,how yuo doing ???");
it.setType("message/rfc822");
chooser = Intent.createChooser(it, "Launch Email");
startActivity(chooser);`